# Taking char 'e' as input and comparing

Tags: c++

OK, so I am doing an exercise in a book, converting different types of money to dollars.  For some reason when I type in 'e' as input for a char variable and compare it to 'e' in an if statement the comparison doesnt work, however if I replace it with another letter it will work fine.  What's the deal?  Heres the code:

```
int main()
{
    const double yen_per_dollar = .013;
    const double pound_per_dollar = 1.55;
    const double euro_per_dollar = 1.29;

    double amount = 1;
    char unit = ' ';

    std::cout << "Please enter a amount followed by a unit (p, y, or e): ";
    std::cin >> amount >> unit;

    if (unit == 'y')
        std::cout << amount << " yen is $" << amount * yen_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
    if (unit == 'p')
        if (amount == 1)
            std::cout << amount << " pound is $" << amount * pound_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
        else
            std::cout << amount << " pounds is $" << amount * pound_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
    if (unit == 'e')
        if (amount == 1)
            std::cout << amount << " euro is $" << amount * euro_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
        else
            std::cout << amount << " euros is $" << amount * euro_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "Sorry, that input isn't in the correct format." << std::endl;
    std::cin >> amount; // Keeps window open
}
```

Comment: ¤ Consider that e.g. `3.14e20` is a valid specification of a `double` value. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Ahhh i thought it might have something to do with that, just remembering notation from grade school, didnt know doubles could be expressed like that.  Thanks.

Comment: Please do not pause your programs artificially at the end with platform-dependent techniques like `system("pause");`. If the problem is that "the window just disappears", then run the program differently, such that the lifetime of the window is not tied to the lifetime of the program. Your program **does not create the command window**, and as such, is not logically responsible for keeping it around.

Comment: You might want to use the conditional operator for tacking on the "s" -- many will disagree, but `<< (amount == 1 ? "s" : "") <<` looks neater to me than repeating the line.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: Well said! I think that should be extended to platform-independent techniques like `std::cin.get()`. OK to copy-paste your message to future offenders?

Comment: Well it was so when someone types in 1 pound it would output "1 pound is X" not "1 pounds is x" :) Thanks Anton that is a better solution just didnt think of it.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Absolutely, and I agree that platform-independent techniques are also a bad idea (and the ones based on `std::cin` also are often not as reliable as they might appear, IIRC). So actually, please edit to fix that part ;)

Comment: @AntonGolov Sometimes we have to do these kinds of things for proper i18n/l10n, but then we should be using something more sophisticated to build our strings than in-order concatenation with `operator<<` etc. (i.e., some kind of positional formatting tool, such as `boost::format`).

Comment: At least in C (with `scanf()` et al; also with `strtod()`), then if you entered `3.14e` as a value (with no digits after the `e`), then the `e` should be left behind for the next input operation to process (which would be unit in the example). Similarly with the input `3.14e+`, the `e` and the `+` should left in the input stream for the next operations to process. However, empirically, in C++ (G++ 4.2.1 LLVM on MacOS X 10.7.2), `2e` is treated as `2` and the `e` is also consumed.  That's a surprising (to me) finding.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of comments but no solution. In fact, I couldn't come up with a good solution, either. The best I could think of is to install a custom `num_get` facet (this alone almost certainly rules the code out as being suitable for being handed in as a homework solution): this is somewhat advanced stuff and I don't think many people would ever think of this.

Other than this, I'd think that you want to data-drive the currencies, i.e. instead of having a code branch for each currency, you want to set up some sort of container describing all currencies (BTW, the plural of Euro is Euro). The resulting program would look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>
#include <ctype.h>

struct currency_get:
    std::num_get<char>
{
    iter_type do_get(iter_type it, iter_type end, std::ios_base&, std::ios_base::iostate& err, double& v) const
    {
        std::string input;
        for (; it != end && (*it == '.' || *it == '-' || *it == '+'
                             || isdigit(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it))); ++it)
        {
            input.push_back(*it);
        }
        errno = 0;
        if (input.empty())
        {
            err |= std::ios_base::failbit;
        }
        else
        {
            v = strtod(input.c_str(), 0);
        }

        return it;
    }
};

int main()
{
    typedef std::tuple<double, std::string, std::string> desc;
    std::map<char, desc> currencies;
    currencies['y'] = desc(0.013, "yen", "yen");
    currencies['p'] = desc(1.55, "pound", "pounds");
    currencies['e'] = desc(1.29, "euro", "euro");

    double amount(0);
    char   currency(' ');
    std::locale loc(std::locale(), new currency_get);
    std::cin.imbue(loc);

    if (std::cin >> amount >> currency)
    {
        std::map<char, desc>::const_iterator it(currencies.find(currency));
        if (it != currencies.end())
        {
            desc const& d(it->second);
            std::cout << amount << " " << (amount == 1? std::get<1>(d): std::get<2>(d)) << " is "
                      << (std::get<0>(d) * amount) << " dollar"
                      << (std::get<0>(d) * amount == 1? "": "s") << "\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "input failed\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the easiest solution is to require the user to type a space between the number and the currency specifier. :)

Answer (score -1):

Here are the suggestions for your program: 
1. Use something like `system("pause");` to pause the program or make change in project settings if you are using Visual Studio so that debug windows waits for you after execution.
2. For next `if` statements you should use else statement and surround by braces. Here's an example,

```
else if (unit == 'p') {
    if (amount == 1)
        std::cout << amount << " pound is $" << amount * pound_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
    else
        std::cout << amount << " pounds is $" << amount * pound_per_dollar << " dollars.\n";
}
```

If you do it in this way your last `else` statement will give you correct result. Otherwise you'll always get "Sorry, that input isn't in the correct format" except for 'e'. Indeed, that's what happening in your program.
3. You should do add a `return 0` statement for your `int` return type of `main` function.
4. Instead of typing std every time you can add this statement once,

```
using namespace std;
```

after your include preprocessors and may omit including `std namespace` afterwards like this,

```
cout << "Please enter a amount followed by a unit (p, y, or e): ";
```

5. e is a reserved char for using with integer/double etc numeric types. e means exponential. When entering currency, use a space before to explicitly tell cin that this e is not part of numerical input. Otherwise, you have to parse the input using strings.

Comment: Note that if you omit an explicit `return` from the end of `main()`, then the effect is as if you wrote `return 0;`.  Only `main()` gets this exemption.  I don't like it much, but it it the standard behaviour (and C99 also supports this, and therefore so does C11).

Comment: using "return 0" will be good. In old days we got compilation time errors in programming contests because of omitting that as most judge compiler were not so..

Comment: Explicit qualification will be good if program is consuming good amount memory including unnecessary namespace members.. For little programs explicit qualifications wouldn't matter much.

Comment: I too disagree on most points.  Point 2 is simply wrong:  `if (a) if (b) stmt; else stmt;` parses the `else` as referring to the inner `if`, as can be seen here: http://ideone.com/atPqk I see what you mean.

Comment: You are right but you misunderstood me. I didn't offend the fundamental syntax of c. I suggested it to make his program work and also comprehensive. I think if you look at his program you will understand.

Comment: Indeed, apoligies, I see what you mean (thought you meant the braces, not the explicit addition of `else` in intermediate cases).

Comment: @DietmarKühl the suggestion system("pause"), in case OP is using IDE like dev-c++, project settings change in case of Visual Studio I suggested to help debugging.